# Pumping out an absolute pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I'm just going over some basics and I have come to a little misunderstanding I have. The question is about pumping out an absolute pressure from a sphere split into two hemispheres and the amount force needed to pull them apart including atmospheric pressure. The way I tried to answer is that the pressure is negative (as pressure has been removed) within the hemisphere and atmospheric pressure would be also is the same 'direction' (I am uncertain about this since pressure is a scalar hence I mean the force due to the pressure), hence the force needed would be proportional to the sum of the internal pressure removed and the atmospheric pressure. However, it is given that is is proportional to the difference between the two. Is there another way I can think about this to come to this conclusion?

Comment: If the pressure inside and outside are the same, there is no net force holding the hemispheres together...

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah I didn't think that one through very hard...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a negative pressure. If you have a very good vacuum . the pressure rom inside can be neglected , so you have only to consider the pressure from outside , or like quoted. the force of the pressure inside is against the one outsides you have to subtract them.
(by the way: you do not "remove" pressure, you remove air and so lower pressure )

Comment: There is no such thing as negative *absolute* pressure, but there is such a thing as negative *gauge* pressure.

Comment: Yes but gauge pressure is just a pressure difference, so what help is your comment?

Comment: It is important to distinguish, because for most non-specialists "pressure" is gauge pressure. You don't inflate your tires to absolute pressure. And that confusion is part of the issue here.